# Date module year submission form - remove drop down menu

Tags: 7, datetime

I was wondering if there was a way to change the format in which the year is input in the date module. By default, it is set as a drop down. I would like the user to input by key stroke. Alternatively, I could set up an integer field as I only need a four digit year.